# how to enable only 1 out of 2 column column graph by default when page loads in highcharts and the 2nd one gets visible when toggled in the legend

Tags: graph, highcharts

I have a hisghchart column graph, which has 2 columns. I want only the 1st column should be visible when the page loads by default. Then when the user toggles the legend, the 2nd column gets visible. Please let me know how it can be made...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [series property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.visible) `visible`.

```
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            visible: false // not shown on page load
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
        }]
```

Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SFZY/).